# Father moves family into house where previous family was killed, might be the killer

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I saw a trailer for a movie a while back where this guy moves into this old house with his family. Strange stuff starts happening they find out the previous family was murdered. Then, surprise surprise, the guy might be the father from the last family who killed everybody. I think the two leads are fairly well known as well.

Sorry, no none of those. I thought I saw the trailer for it in 2011, 2012, or the beginning of 2013. So I'm sure it's fairly new. I also think it's supposed to have been out already, so I don't think it'd still be in the making or "post-production." It didn't look low budget or cheesy or anything so I'm pretty sure it was a Hollywood film. I think the main guy might have also spent some time in a psychiatric hospital?

Comment: Can you provide little more detail, like is it Hollywood film, how old is the film or when did you watched it etc etc....

Comment: Is it [The Messengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Messengers_%28film%29) or [The Amityville Horror (2005)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amityville_Horror_%282005_film%29) , both movies has know names and description also matches.

Comment: Sounds somewhat like [Sinister (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1922777) starring Ethan Hawke, but not a perfect fit given your description.

Comment: I know the one you mean! I am trying to find it to, i believe it was called '**The** (something like mystery or happpening) **at** (something) **mansion**' but i'm struggling to find it! its quite old, like 7-10 years old.

Comment: It's [Cold Creek Manor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0331468/) a 2003 thriller.

Comment: The name of the movie is Sinister

Answer (score 5):

It might be [The Messengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Messengers_%28film%29) or [The Amityville Horror (2005)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amityville_Horror_%282005_film%29), both movies have known actors and description also matches.

In The Messengers, the father of the last family turned out to be killer in end and try to kill this family, too. On the other hand in The Amityville Horror the new family's father try to kill his family ( Possessed by the same entity which made the previous family killed ).

Comment: Messengers much more likely than Amityville Horror (assuming the remake of AH is basically the same plot as the original ... have not seen the remake, though should have since I'm a Ryan Reynolds fan).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the Amytiville Horror to me. It could be the origional or the 2005 remake

The details all fit except the part where you say the killer could be the same guy from the previous familt. Saying that, I think I remember a scene where a character states the current father strongly resembles the previous killer.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but are you thinking of Dream House with Daniel Craig?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange! I changed your answer to a question, to sound more respectful. I also added a link to the trailer, and think you're probably right. Good job.

Comment: Just watched Dream House last night.  Sounds like an exact match to me.

Answer (score 2):

If the "old house" is a large hotel closed for the winter, that could describe [*The Shining* (1980)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081505/) well.  I am a little fuzzy because the plot is not that clear cut—it could be the father lived years before and killed a lot of people.  Or it could be an ancestor.

*The Shining* stars Jack Nicholson and Shelley Duvall.  It was written by Stephen King and directed by Stanley Kubrick.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like The Messengers, which stars Kristen Steward (pre-Twilight) and Dylan McDermott among others.

The basic premise is a family (Mom, Dad, teenage daughter and baby boy) move to North Dakota farm for a fresh start after the teen got in some trouble in their old town. Paranormal things start happening around the baby and teen, but the parents brush it off as the teen acting out and making up things just to be difficult. The teen makes a friend and confidant in town who helps her investigate the place and they find out the last people who lived there vanished mysteriously- that's about where things pick up and I don't want to spoil it for those who haven't seen it, so [here's the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97RegaPXgO0).

Comment: Have you missed the already existing answer? Your answer seems duplicate of it, adding no new value.

Answer (score 0):

Also sounds like the 2013 movie Oculus - the son spent time in a psychiatric hospital and is one of the two main characters (a brother and sister).